# Cannot write to sqlite from another activity

Tags: android, sqlite, getwritabledatabase

I try to call a method and write to my database from another activity in android but my app crashes because it cannot write. My activity does not have On Create because it does not need it. Therefore I have this code:
`DB db = new DB(ServSearcher.this);` which I want to give me acess to my Database and then I use my method below like:

```
List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
for (Contact cn : contacts) {
    db.addContact(new Contact(var, getTime()));
```

Here is my logcat error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:268)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
        at com.android.SecondActivity.DB.getAllContacts(DB.java:88)
        at com.android.SecondActivity.ServSearcher$5.onAvailable(ServSearcher.java:189)
```

I think it is obvious that my app cannot write to database so this line is wrong `DB db = new DB(ServSearcher.this);` or at least does not gives me access, any ideas?

**edit after V_J comment:**

Here is my method on DB

```
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {

        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setTime(cursor.getInt(0));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}
```

Comment: Post your DB Code for Reference

Comment: I think you are using `ServSearcher.this` as a context. right? without activitie's super method you can't access context. you will get `null`

Comment: Post your complete code.

Comment: @Boss so how should I change that?

Comment: @V_J you mean my method in my DB

Comment: @We'reAllMadHere: Yes.

Comment: Please show us where are you initializing the `db` variable.

Comment: I have already posted in my question Boss, its that line that I am talking about, please take a look again

Comment: Below here: `public ServSearcher(Context Context, WifiP2pManager Manager, WifiP2pManager.Channel Channel, WifiBase.WifiStatusCallBack handler, String serviceType) {...in a public void Start...my method`

Comment: @We'reAllMadHere: You can also pass the context as a parameter of the 'getAllContacts' function. 
getAllContacts(Context context){.....your code.....}

And rewrite the code as:
db = new DatabaseHelper(context);

But OTOH using singleton pattern is a better way of dealing with such issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can solve your problem with the singleton pattern, I leave a link below to your explanation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: Can you be more specific please?

Comment: this is an example with a Scanner, but you can use any object, and share a single instance

public class SingletonExample {

 static Scanner in;
 
 public static Scanner getScanner(){
  
  if(in == null){
   in = new Scanner(System.in);
  }
  return in;
 }
 
}